# Javascript function takes 2 click to fire

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

i have a javascript function to open and close a modal it checks if the modal is open and closed but it takes 2 clicks the first time to fire off until you refresh the page then you have to click 2 time again.

Javascript:

```
function ToggleModal(Box) {
        var Modal = document.getElementById(Box);
        var Display = Modal.style.display;

        if(Display == 'none')
        {
            Modal.style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('Wrapper').style.overflow = 'hidden';
        }
        else
        {
            Modal.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

CSS:

```
.Modal {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../IMG/Modal.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

my div:

```
<div id="Login" class="Modal">
    <div id="LoginForm" class="Form">
        <div class="ModalTitle">Sign In <a href="#" class="Toggle" onclick="ToggleModal('Login');"></a></div>
        <div class="ModalBody">
            <form id="LForm" action="/Assets/PHP/Login/Login.php" method="POST">
                <label for="User">Username:</label>
                <input id="User" type="text" name="User" class="Input" placeholder="Username" />

                <label for="Pass">Password:</label>
                <input id="Pass" type="password" name="Pass" class="Input" placeholder="Password" />
            </form>
            <div class="Clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

there are no styles for the Logo div id.

Comment: An advice, don't use caps for everything. Caps are a convention for constructors.

Comment: i was thinking it goes through the if statement, the first time it doesnt have a display of none so the else sets it to none then when you click it again it sees display none.

Comment: I don't get it, how do you click something that is hidden ?

Comment: im clicking a link... in the header part of my page i didnt include it here

Comment: If you want to encourage people to answer your question, you should include just enough code to run and demonstrate your problem. See here for more - http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, the initial style is something other than "block" or "none".

The first time you click, `(Display == 'none')` is false, so display is set to "none" (so your modal doesn't appear).

The second time, `(Display == 'none')` is true, so display is set to "block".

If that's the case, you should be able to fix it by changing `(Display == 'none')` to `(Display != 'block')`.

Comment: Some part of your code you haven't posted is probably changing the display property. Kudos for sharing what you believe to be the relevant part of the code.

Comment: the link i clicked to toggle this function doesnt do anything but fire it. that part is irrelavent because it didnt affect anything.